# Save local storage across tests to avoid re-authentication

Tags: cypress

I'm wondering if it is possible to save the state of localStorage across tests. 
Mainly because I want to avoid re-authentication on each test. I realize that I can create a command that sends an API request to our backend to avoid going through the auth flow but for various reasons this won't work in my situation.

I am asking if it possible to have a workflow like this:

1. Go to login page: Authenticate get back response and save session to local storage
2. Persist local storage somehow...
3. Go through other tests as authenticated user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

1. Go to login page: Authenticate
   At this point we have data we want to persist between tests in localStorage but we are not allowed to whitelist localStorage.
   However, we are allow to [whitelist cookies](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies.html#Preserve-Once)

I have some code like this inside my `support/commands.js` that act as helpers

```
const sessionKeys = {
  authTokens: 'auth.tokens',
  sessionConfig: 'session.config',
};

// The concatenation of username and cid will be the key to set the session
Cypress.Commands.add('persistSession', (key) => {

  const authTokens = localStorage.getItem(key);

  cy.setCookie(key, authTokens);
});

Cypress.Commands.add('restoreSession', (key) => {
  cy.getCookie(key).then(authTokens => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, authTokens.value);
  });

});
```

2. So we call `cy.persistSession(key)` after we login, which means we have all the authentication saved as cookies which are whitelisted inside of `support/index.js` with code.

Like this:

```
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
  whitelist: function(cookie){
    // Persist auth stuff
    const reAuthTokens = new RegExp('.*auth\.tokens');
    if(reAuthTokens.test(cookie.name)){
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
});
```

3. Now anytime we need our auth tokens inside our other tests before running them we `cy.restoreSession(key)` and we should be good!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [cypress-localstorage-commands](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-localstorage-commands) package to persist localStorage between tests, so you'll be able to do login only once:

In support/commands.js:

```js
import "cypress-localstorage-commands";
```

In your tests:

```js
before(() => {
  // Do your login stuff here
  cy.saveLocalStorage();
});

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.restoreLocalStorage();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the useful link that solves my problem like yours: Preserve cookies through multiple tests

my code like:

```js
    const login = () => { 
      cy.visit('http://0.0.0.0:8080/#/login');    
      cy.get('#username').type('username'); 
      cy.get('#password').type('1234password$'); 
      cy.get('#login-button').click();
    }

    describe('UI', () => {
      // beforeEach(login);
      beforeEach(() => {
        login(); 
        Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('session_id', 'remember_token'); 
      });
    });
```

hope can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Anything you can do in JS you can do in a cypress test. If you have some way to store creds (auth token, etc.) in local storage, I see no reason why you can't do that. If cypress is clearing out your local storage between tests, you will have to write a beforeEach hook that saves an authenticated token (hard-coded by you) to local storage before each test.