# I want to persist/preserve login in all spec files instead of logging in again and again for every file

Tags: authentication, cypress, persist, preserve

I want to persist/preserve login in all spec files instead of logging again and again for every file: I found solution for multiple tests is a single file but I need solution for multiple tests for multiple specs files

> [Save local storage across tests to avoid re-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50393987/save-local-storage-across-tests-to-avoid-re-authentication)
>
> [Set local storage in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56431316/set-local-storage-in-cypress)
>
> https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-localstorage-commands

These are solutions for single file with multiple tests but I need solution for multiple files

Comment: **Romi** do you have solution please

Comment: You can try to write the login data into a fixture file after the successful login. Then in every test you can rely on this fixture file and reuse it. To pass the necessary filename to all tests, you could name the fixture `login_xx.json` where `xxx` is e.g. the date of the first run. Then in all subsequent tests you read the latest json file. Using this approach you will not need to share any JS data among the tests

Comment: @JosefBiehler
Please see this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59266282/cypress-i-want-run-tests-in-100-spec-files-by-login-one-time-and-persist-login/59269251?noredirect=1#comment104781126_59269251

I tried this approach but it did not work
please can you send me any code example please

Answer (score -1):

The [cypress-localstorage-commands](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-localstorage-commands) package persists localStorage even between different tests files, this is its default behavior. As it describes in its documentation, it also provides a `clearLocalStorageSnapshot` command to clean the localStorage between test files if needed.

Note that you'll have to restore the localStorage in every test file using the `cy.restoreLocalStorage()` command:

```js
describe("Tests file 1", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.restoreLocalStorage();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    cy.saveLocalStorage();
  });
});
```

```js
describe("Tests file 2", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.restoreLocalStorage();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    cy.saveLocalStorage();
  });
});
```